# Image upload links not always clear

Tags: bug, design, uploader

I'm admiring the new Image Uploading tool. Nice. Thanks.

However, it seems to be mixing site-specific CSS with non-site-specific CSS, which means the links aren't clear on some sites.

For example, Skeptics.SE, the link is indistinguishable:

> [image]

It took me a while to work out where to click to invoke this link.

Whereas on meta.stackexchange.com, it looks good:

> [image]

Comment: The black link color on Skeptics has probably caused more design bugs than everything else combined. I'd guess that this will be fixed with the new CSS update